# Read .txt file and display into different button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to display some text on my button but I can only display those text on 1 button. My buttons are separated like `Button1.Text`, `Button2.Text`, and `Button3.Text` and my `.txt` file can only be displayed in `Button1.Text`. Here is the code that I did so far.

```
Private Sub FormMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Dim R As New IO.StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
                Button1.Text = R.ReadToEnd()
                R.Close()
End Sub
```

Inside my `.txt` file got something like

```
First Button
Second Button
Third Button
```

and I want my system be able to read them and display into each of the button. How to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like...

```
Private Sub FormMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt")
    For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length
        Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find("Button" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctl) Then
            ctl.Text = lines(i - 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I try it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub FormMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim R As New IO.StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
            Dim words As String() = R.ReadToEnd().Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine})
            Button1.Text = words(0)
            Button2.Text = words(1)
            Button3.Text = words(2)
            R.Close()
End Sub
```